# Configuring Azure App Service to pull from ACR, but nothing works and no Deployment logs

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I'm trying a simple deployment of a Docker image with a hello world Python flask app, which I've pushed to ACR successfully.  I've tried configuring the App Service to pull from ACR in many different ways, but the Deployment Center logs never show any activity or error message.  I'm not even sure it's a permissions issue or not because the logs just show just a oneliner:

`2023_04_25_lw0sdlwk0007ZT_docker.log:`

(I assume it's a permissions issue though because it doesn't even pull the image)

1. The ACR and App Service app are under the same resource group.
2. I've tried with a system-assigned managed identity and a user-assigned managed identity.  Both have the AcrPull permissions to the ACR.  I've also tried with using
3. I've tried using a service principal and app service config with DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL, DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME, and DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD
4. I've tried so many different articles:

- [Migrate custom software to Azure App Service using a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=azure-portal#configure-app-service-to-deploy-the-image-from-the-registry)
- [Run a custom container in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=python&pivots=container-linux-vscode)
- [Configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=debian#use-managed-identity-to-pull-image-from-azure-container-registry)
- [Deploy a containerized Python app to App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-containerize-deploy-python-web-app-azure-04?tabs=azure-portal%2Cterminal-bash)

4. I've tried deploying straight from vs.code via the docker tab on the left with "Deploy Image to Azure App Service...".  This creates the webapp and grants the correct permissions to pull from the ACR.

This is quite frustrating to not even see logs why deployment is failing.  Where do I even start to debug or pinpoint where the failure is?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

# Path: /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv
RUN python3 -m venv ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Path: /app/requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port", "80" ]
```

app.py:

```py
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Blahblahblah"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is there a way to manually trigger/start a deployment?  It's almost like a worker that's responsible for running the deployment is either stuck or not running (?)

Thanks...

**UPDATE 1**
I tried @pravallika suggestions and no luck, completely empty deployment logs.

Here's the IAM roles, "ckairegistry" is the registry I'm deploying from.

[image: IAM]

Here are the deployment logs, even after 15minutes

[image: Empty Deployment logs after 15minutes]

Here are the web app settings:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This kind of nonsense is everything that is wrong with Azure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an issue with the deployment of your Docker image to the App Service.

1. Check the Docker logs
2. Check the App Service logs in App Service>Diagnose and solve problems>Log stream section. to figure out the errors during the deployment.
3. Try giving the "Managed Application Contributor Role" permission to your registry.
4. Re-check if App Service is configured to pull images from the correct repository and tag.
5. Make sure that the Docker image is configured correctly and that it's working as expected and try re-deploying the Docker image.

---

***I have tried below steps, and it worked for me.Check if this helps you to achieve your requirement:***

- Created a sample Hello world Python flask application:

[image]
requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.1.0
```

Created Dockerfile

```
FROM  python:3.10.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR  /app
COPY  requirements.txt  requirements.txt
RUN  pip3  install  -r  requirements.txt

COPY..

EXPOSE  5000

CMD  [  "python3",  "-m"  ,  "flask",  "run",  "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

*Build a docker image of the application and push the same using below commands:*

```
docker build -t <docker_image:tag> .
docker push <docker_image:tag>
```

[image]
[image]

*Commands to build and push the docker image to Azure ACR:*

```
az login
az acr login -n <your_registry_name>
docker build -t <registry_name>.azureacr.io/<docker_image:tag> .
docker push <registry_name>.azureacr.io/<docker_image:tag>
```

[image]

*In portal, Add WEBSITES_PORT:<port_number> in App service> Configuration> Application Settings.*
[image]

*Added my registry in IAM of webapp and given owner access.*
[image]

*Enabled Admin credentials in my registry:*
[image]

*Choosing Admin Credentials as Authentication:*
[image]
*Select File System in App Service> App Service Logs>Application logging to avoid 'Logging is not enabled for this container' errors.*
[image]
*I could pull and deploy image from ACR to Azure Web App.*
[image]

Comment: Thanks @pravallika-kv for the detailed response.  I'm trying it out right now.  1) How did you add registry account as service principal for your webapp?  I can only select the registry as a "managed identity" in IAM->Add Role.  I followed same steps and am waiting on the deployment.  Deployment logs show empty logs.  Is there a way to manually trigger deployment?

Comment: Go to Web App->IAM->Select 'Owner' in ['Priviliged administrator roles'](https://i.imgur.com/b85snDr.png) section and select 'user,group or service principal in ['Assign Access to'](https://i.imgur.com/b85snDr.png) section. Click on Add Members, search and select your registry as shown in the [Image](https://i.imgur.com/b85snDr.png).

Comment: you can deploy the image to web app directly from ACR. Open your registry->Repositories-> select your image-> click on the dots in the right end of the image-> select deploy to web app. Check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/doj1c4k.png) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will give those a try. I discovered that after creating the app service under a new resource group and new app service plan, the deployment job kicks in now!  I'm not sure why - my theory is the worker processes were overloaded with other app service, dbs, and resources running.  In deployment center, I used managed identity->system assigned.  It is strange, sometimes the deployment worker kicks off, sometimes it doesn't and with no logs.  I haven't figured it out yet.